# Signature or API Key validation using PHP

Tags: php, api, signature

I would like to provide an API for one of my php application. How can I prevent unauthorized acces of API?
Tried to provide an API key for every customer one who register but I think it may fail when use with different domains.
What is the idea behind signature validation or api key validation. Please give me some advice

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I handle authorization to an API written in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830970/how-do-i-handle-authorization-to-an-api-written-in-php)

Answer (score 7):

API keys can be used to control the query rate, if they are visible. Meaning you will not allow more than N requests per minute per key per ip or something like that. They are not really a means of security,but of identity.

Now, how do you go about making sure this key is actually used by the user to whom it belongs?

One way of doing that is request signature. when you pass a request with a bunch of parameters (a=x&b=y...), you create a signature only the client and the server can create or validate. this is done by taking the parameters and values, and creating an MD5 or SHA1 sum of them, adding a secret variable, or salt, to the string. this variable is never sent on the wire and is visible to the user by its admin console over https only. Be sure to sort the parameters alphabetically before hashing, though!

so, if my parameters are: `foo=bar&bar=baz`, I will sort the dictionary of parameters, add the secret `$SECRET='asd32efe32ef2df23'` and create: `$sig = md5('bar=baz&foo=bar'.$SECRET);` then can just add `&sig={$sig}` to the request. the other side will do the same with the parameters (excluding `sig`) and validate it.

A good idea would be to change the secret per session or every once in a while. this can be done over HTTPS using a password or SSL certificate.

Edit: one thing you usually add to make it more secure, is an incrementing request id that is also sent unencrypted over the wire, and is used in the hashing process. this prevents two identical requests from having the same signature, and prevents a replay attack (the attacker resends a command). When you do that, you need to allow some grace in the server for out of order requests (i.e. the client sent them by order, but because of networks speed, you can see them as 100, 102, 101 on the server).

Comment: A signature is essentially exactly the same as an API key and provides exactly the same functionality (confirmation of identity). The only difference is that in a signed request the API key itself is never sent over the wire, which minimizes chances of it leaking to a third party. It doesn't change the fact that it's simply a secret, opaque token the user has, which uniquely identifies him.

Comment: I consider the API key to be an open token available to everyone, since you do not encrypt every API call normally. The API is like your user name, and since you cannot pass the password, you pass some secret based on it, which is the signature.